# Calling SCIM APIs: authorization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My client has Azure AD and wants to provision users in Salesforce via SCIM. Azure is asking for two pieces of information to complete the configuration:

- Tenant URL
- Secret token

Salesforce provides minimal documentation on how to provide this information to Azure.  From what I have found, the tenant URL probably looks something like:  http://blahblah.my.salesforce.com/services/scim or maybe https://blahblah.my.salesforce.com/services/scim/v2

The big question is "what is the secret token?"  I have tried providing three different Salesforce-generated tokens into this field, but none of them work:

- The sys admin's security token
- A connected app's consumer secret
- A Shield-generated tenant secret (a long-shot guess)

Comment: The SCIM endpoints are [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.identity_scim_rest_api.htm&type=5). All SF REST APIs incl. SCIM require a bearer token to authorize the caller. You obtain the token via oAuth by choosing an [appropriate flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you for the response @identigral.  I did read the documentation, but it doesn't help with the Azure configuration, which is asking for a "secret token".  In the Salesforce-specific connector, it asked for a "secret token", which was supposed to be the user's security token.  For this generic connector, I don't know what to put in this field.  Even in the Salesforce-specific connector, I didn't create a connected app... I just supplied the tenant URL and user info.

Comment: The token needed for SCIM is an access token obtained via oAuth. The term "secret token" is a generic label by Azure.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.  The connection was successful after I generated a bearer token and put that into the Azure configuration.